# Tagged unions (aka variant) in C++ with the same type multiple times

Tags: c++, boost, ocaml, variant

I need to create an union, but 2 members of the union would have the same type, thus I need a way to identify them. For example in OCaml :

```
type A = 
  | B of int
  | C of float
  | D of float
```

Boost.Variant doesn't seem to support this case, is there a known library which supports that ?

Comment: Why two of the same `type`? Only one member of a union can be used at any one time.

Comment: I know but there are cases when you would like to distringuish to member even if they have the same underlying type. A small example would be an Expr type with 2 members IntConst of int and IntMutable of int.

Comment: But there must be some other flag somewhere (containing `struct` or `class`) that indicates which member of the union is _active_? That could be used to provide the additional required meaning.

Comment: @maattdd: So what you need is a single type and a tag that distinguishes the different flavor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to do this, I think your best option is to wrap the same-but-different-types into a struct which then lets the boost variant visit the proper one:

```
struct Speed
{
    float val_;
};

struct Darkness
{
    float val_;
};
```

You *might* be able to use `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` to do this automatically but I'm not sure it's guaranteed to generate types legal for use in a union (although it would probably be fine in a variant).

Answer (score 3):

The c++ code here:

http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/sandbox/variadic_templates/boost/composite_storage/pack/container_one_of_maybe.hpp

is truly a tagged union in that it can contain duplicate types.  One nice feature
is the tags can be enumerations; hence, the tags can have meaningful names.

Unfortunately, the compile time cost is pretty bad, I guess, because the implementation
uses recursive inheritance.  OTOH, maybe compilers will eventually figure out a way
to lessen the compile time cost.

OTOH, if you want to stick with boost::variant, you could wrap the types,
as Mark B suggested.  However, instead of Mark B's descriptive class names,
which require some thought, you could use `fusion::pair<mpl::int_<tag>,T_tag>`
where `T_tag` is the tag-th element in the source `fusion::vector`.  IOW:

```
variant
< fusion::pair<mpl::int_<1>,T1>
, fusion::pair<mpl::int_<2>,T2>
...
, fusion::pair<mpl::int_<n>,Tn>
>
```

As the fusion docs:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/support/pair.html

say, `fusion::pair` only allocates space for the 2nd template argument; hence,
this should not take any more room than `boost::variant<T1,T2,...,Tn>`.

HTH.

-regards,
Larry

Answer (score 3):

You cannot at the moment but [C++17's implementation of `std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) fortunately allows it:

> A variant is permitted to hold the same type more than once, and to hold differently cv-qualified versions of the same type.

Unlike with the boost version, you can get values by index, something like this (not tested):

```
// Construct a variant with the second value set.
variant<string, string, string> s(std::in_place_index<1>, "Hello");
// Get the second value.
string first = std::get<1>(s);
```

Michael Park has written [a C++14 implementation of C++17's `std::variant`](https://github.com/mpark/variant).